# Change Div Position from Absolute to Fixed with Horizontal Scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, horizontal-scrolling

I have a site that scrolls horizontally using the horizontal scroll plugin over at https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel. No problems there.

My questions is, I have a 250px wide div with 100% height that starts 100px from the right side of the screen. As I scroll (horizontally), the div scrolls towards the left and eventually disappears off the screen. The div has a Position set to Absolute. What I would like is the div to become fixed to left hand side of the screen once the div hits that left side of the browser window.

I'm guessing I need to use JS to change the CSS of the div once it reaches a particular place (far left) on the screen. I've seen quite a few sites achieve this with vertical scrolling, where a menu bar becomes fixed at the top of the screen once it hits the top. The menu may have started half way down the page and moved upwards on scroll. I'm just wanting to achieve the same effect on a horizontal plane.

I'm relatively new to code in general, and am brand new to Javascript. I may be biting off more than I can chew, but I like a challenge. Thanks anyone for your help.

The CSS code I would be changing is

```
#header {
    width: 250px;
    background: rgba(22,22,22,.85);
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: calc(100% - 350px);
    z-index: 999;
}
```

then change to

```
#header {
    width: 250px;
    background: rgba(22,22,22,.85);
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: 0px;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: If you provide some work what you have done, I mean code.. then definitely we can help u.. This dont seem as big prob but u need to show us some code so that we can deal with it..

Comment: Hi Kaushik. Thanks for the response. I've added the CSS that I believe would need to be changed in the question above. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I tried as per what I understood from your question.. n yea I have user javascript..

HTML:

```
<div id="headerSlideContainer">

    <div id="headerSlideContent">

        Header content goes here!

    </div>
    <div id="new">
        Other Contents
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#headerSlideContainer {
    position: absolute;

    top:0px;
    width: 100%;

   height:1000px;
    background: black;
}
#headerSlideContent {
    width: 250px;
    background-color:red;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: 0px;
    z-index: 999;
}

#new{
    top:60px;
    z-index:2;
    height:100px;
    background:Orange;
    position:absolute;
    color: white;

}
```

and js:

```
$(function() {

    var bar = $('#headerSlideContainer');
    var top = bar.css('top');
    $(window).scroll(function() {

        if($(this).scrollright() > 100) {
            bar.stop().animate({'top' : '5px'}, 500);
        } else {
            bar.stop().animate({'top' : top}, 500);
        }
    });
});
```

change that scrollright amount as needed.. If scrollright doesnt work then try scrollleft().. Let me know if you have any prob..

Comment: Thanks mate. Appreciate the answer. I'll let you know how I go and if it works for me.

Comment: Hey mate. Am playing with it now. Check this link for a dummy of the side-scrolling I'm working with. Just want to make sure I explained the scenario well. http://healthyselfie.com/photosite You may have to load it in Chrome as I'm only playing at the moment and have only tested there.

Comment: K.. Dat was enuf for me to understand the scenario.. Well the above trick whatever I have mentioned as answer will definitely work, may be some rework will be needed as per ur requirement.. and you also have to make use of z-index which will will be the main part for this to workout.. You got it how to do or should I work on it...:)

Comment: Anytime bro...Well.. All the best...:)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a post explaining how to do this vertically, but the same concepts should apply in your case too.

The tutorial: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/fixed-floating-elements/

The demo: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/fixedfloat.html

Comment: Thanks mate for the links. I'll check it out and let you know how I go.